# Why Mass is considered as a property in gravity theories rather than a unit?

Tags: gravity, newtonian-gravity, mass, units

Einstein's GR or Newton's equation uses mass as a property that causes gravity (physical phenomena)? For any physical phenomena to occur, there must be physical/chemical/biological/etc. action requires. for Mass it is not there.

Comment: Gordon Kane wrote a very excellent article for Scientific American a few years ago, "The Mysteries of Mass." You can probably find the text through a Google search.

Answer (score 1):

In Newtonian gravity, mass is not just a number, it also has a dimension which is the gravitational charge, which determines the gravitational field. This gravitational charge is a physical property. However, Newton could not provide any explanation for how these gravitational charges could act over a distance. Furthermore, the gravitational charge happens to be exactly the same as inertial mass (which in turn is another type of charge) in non-relativistic situations, and Einstein's motivation for creating GR was to explain this mysterious equivalence.

In GR, the concept of a scalar gravitational charge is extended to the stress-energy tensor, which has 10 independent components. In the GR field equation this is equal to the Einstein tensor, which is a function of the geometry of spacetime. If you interpret this equation literally, mass is simply a measure of local spacetime curvature. The ultimate cause of this curvature is of course still a mystery.